# Test if it is QJsonObject or QJsonArray in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am supposed to receive a `QJsonObject` from server, which will contain an `QJsonObject` or `QJsonArray` with name "List". I mean, "List" can be either a `QJsonObject` or `QJsonArray`. So how to check if "List" is a `QJsonObject` or a `QJsonArray`?

The received `QJsonDocument` could be one of the two bellow writen formats

1) Here "List" is a `QJsonArray`

```
{
  "Data":
         {
           "List":
             [
                {
                   "name": "something",
                   "id": "number"
                },
                {
                   "name": "something",
                   "id": "number"
                },
                {
                   "name":"something",
                   "id": "number"
               }
            ] 
        } 
}
```

2) Here "List" is a `QJsonObject`

```
{
   "Data":
          {
            "List":
               {
                  "name": "something",
                  "id": "number"
               }
          }
}
```

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first code that you sample is not a valid json, use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have edited the sample

Comment: I assumed that json is the one you wanted to show for what I had explained in my solution.

Comment: Yes, your solution is exactly relevant to my sample. I just need to check if it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first json that samples is invalid so I'll wait for you to correct it to point out the correct test, in the case of the second one only missing a comma. But going to the point when you access a field of a `QJsonObject` or `QJsonArray` it returns a `QJsonValueRef` which is a helper that handles several types of data, and for you know if it is a `QJsonObject` or a `QJsonArray` you must use the method [`isObject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#isObject) or [`isArray()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#isArray) :

```
const QByteArray json = R"(
                          {
                              "Data": {
                                  "List": {
                                      "name": "something",
                                      "id": "number"
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                          )";

QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(json);
QJsonObject obj = doc.object();
QJsonValueRef list_ref = doc["Data"].toObject()["List"];

if(list_ref.isObject())
    qDebug()<< list_ref <<"is Object";
else if (list_ref.isArray()) {
    qDebug()<< list_ref << "is array";
}
```

Output:

```
QJsonValue(object, QJsonObject({"id":"number","name":"something"})) is Object
```

---

Whereas in your first example you wanted to show the following valid json:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "List": [{
            "name": "something",
            "id": "number"
        }, {
            "name": "something",
            "id": "number"
        }, {
            "name": "something",
            "id": "number"
        }]
    }
}
```

If you use the same method you get:

```
QJsonValue(array, QJsonArray([{"id":"number","name":"something"},{"id":"number","name":"something"},{"id":"number","name":"something"}])) 
is array
```

Comment: Thanks @eyllansec. isObject() and isArray() method works for me fine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already parsed your server response into a valid `QJsonObject`. Using the [`QJsonValue QJsonObject::operator[](QString)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#operator-5b-5d) we retrieve a `QJsonValue` which is basically a variant type. You can query the type of the value by various `bool QJsonValue::is*()` methods. In your case you need [`bool QJsonValue::isArray()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#isArray) and [`bool QJsonIsObject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#isArray).

```
auto dataNode = serverResponse["Data"];
if(dataNode.isObject()) {
  auto dataObject = dataNode.toObject();
  // handle object case
}
else if(dataNode.isArray()) {
  auto dataArray = dataNode.toArray();
  // handle array case
}
```

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.12 and the local dataNode has no methods called isObject or isArray.